# Get response for uncaught Exceptions using process.on

Tags: node.js

I am able to caught uncaught Exceptions in Node.js using

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception, req, res) {
  console.log("error======== >>>>>>>>>  ",exception);
})
```

But i want to send an error message in the `res.send({error:"Something broke"})` when my code goes in any exception rather than just halting it in time out.

I google it but could not find anything helpful.

i added `process.exit(1)` but it could not help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not wise to continue operations after `uncaughtException` is hit. You should let the child die and spawn a fresh process to hand further requests.

More on this can be found here:

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_warning_using_uncaughtexception_correctly